# Elgato Wave 3 stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, ubuntu-22.04

Some update for Ubuntu 20.04 between last monday and yesterday made my Elgato Wave 3 (USB microphone) stop working. Has been working fine before. Finally tried upgrading to 22.04 in the hope it would fix things, but no.
Elgato Wave 3 shows a red circle, which means it's not communicating (properly) with the OS.
I tried booting on an earlier kernel, because I've previously had similar issues with my blu-ray burner which was caused by the kernel. But no such luck this time.
Can anyone help with this? Any specific package(s) I could try to reinstall? Other suggestions? Thanks.